# What is my best option for showing a dialog from a child Widget if that child widget is being disposed?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ChangeNotifier model that exposes an enum that contains N states. I have a StatelessWidget that represents the root widget of a screen. For each of the N states of my model, I display a different UI in the root widget page. To make this code bite sized and manageable, I have the root widget display a different StatelessWidgets, each which correspond to a specific state.

So for states A, B, C, I have StatelessWidgetA, StatelessWidgetB, and StatelessWidgetC. The root widget switches between these sub widgets on state changes.

Each one of these sub-widgets displays nested dialogs on button presses. Eg..

```
dialog1 -> "Are you sure you want to do this operation?"
dialog2 -> "Operation succeeded!!"
```

In between the second and first dialog showing, the state changes, and the sub widget (and context) showing the dialog are disposed because a state change propagate a build on the root widget.

When this happens I get the following error...

```
FlutterError (Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.)
```

My question is less about what is going wrong (it is pretty obvious), but more about what is a new design for this page that does not cause this error?

1. I like having a bunch on stateless sub-widgets to organize the code by state.
2. I ideally don't want to pass function callback for each sub-widget, because that defeats the puspose of making the top level build less verbose.

Is there a clean way to have these subwidgets display dialogs with a context scoped to the top level root widget?

**I have provided a single file flutter app that is a minimal reproducible example...**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

void showAlertDialog({
  required BuildContext context,
  required String title,
  required String body,
  required bool showCancelOption,
  Function? onConfirm,
}) {
  showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      List<Widget> actions = [
        TextButton(
          child: const Text("OK"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            if (onConfirm != null) {
              onConfirm();
            }
          },
        ),
      ];

      if (showCancelOption) {
        actions.add(
          TextButton(
            child: const Text("Cancel"),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          ),
        );
      }

      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(title),
        content: Text(body),
        actions: actions,
      );
    },
  );
}

enum MyState {
  one,
  transition,
  two,
}

class MyStateModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  MyState _state = MyState.one;
  MyState get state => _state;
  Future<bool> transitionState() async {
    var newState = _state == MyState.one ? MyState.two : MyState.one;
    _state = MyState.transition;
    notifyListeners();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500)); // fake some request operation
    _state = newState;
    notifyListeners();
    return true;
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyStateModel>(
      create: (context) => MyStateModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var model = Provider.of<MyStateModel>(context);
    Widget body;
    // this build method is nice and small, and
    switch (model.state) {
      case MyState.one:
        body = const StateOneWidget();
        break;
      case MyState.transition:
        body = StateTransitionWidget();
        break;
      case MyState.two:
        body = const StateTwoWidget();
        break;
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: body,
    );
  }
}

class StateOneWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const StateOneWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text("Goto State Two"),
        onPressed: () {
          showAlertDialog(
            context: context,
            title: "Goto State Two?",
            body: "This will go to state two.",
            showCancelOption: true,
            onConfirm: () async {
              var model = Provider.of<MyStateModel>(context, listen: false);
              var success = await model.transitionState();
              if (success) {
                showAlertDialog(
                  context: context,
                  title: "Got State Two",
                  body: "Success!!",
                  showCancelOption: false,
                );
              }
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StateTwoWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const StateTwoWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text("Goto State One"),
        onPressed: () {
          showAlertDialog(
            context: context,
            title: "Goto State One?",
            body: "This will go to state one.",
            showCancelOption: true,
            onConfirm: () async {
              var model = Provider.of<MyStateModel>(context, listen: false);
              var success = await model.transitionState();
              if (success) {
                showAlertDialog(
                  context: context,
                  title: "Got State One",
                  body: "Success!!",
                  showCancelOption: false,
                );
              }
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StateTransitionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const StateTransitionWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `dialogContext` to your classes, and pass the build context from MyHomePage in the constructor. Then use this `dialogContext` as context in the `showAlertDialog` functions:

```
case MyState.one:
        body = StateOneWidget(dialogContext: context);
```

```
class StateOneWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  BuildContext dialogContext;
  StateOneWidget({required this.dialogContext, Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

```
 showAlertDialog(
            context: dialogContext,
```